# How to convert all values in a column to floating point values in R?

Tags: r, statistics, type-conversion

I have a dataframe like this:

```
ID     A     B     
 0    0052  225  
 1   00558  305  
 2    0855  250  
...              ...
```

All I want is to change the values of column 'A' in a way, that it looks like this, with only the last two digits as floating point values and the third last in front of the decimal point:

```
ID    A     B    
 0   0.52  225  
 1   5.58  305  
 2   8.55  250  
...             ...
```

---

I am new to R, if you know some good basic guidelines or books for scientific plotting, let me know. :-)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try `as.numeric(df$A)/100`.

Comment: Thanks, I can see that it works as intended in the console, but after I plot it it still uses the old values. 
How do I add the output of the function to the already existing data frame and replace the old column with it?

Comment: Assign the value back: `df$A<-as.numeric(df$A)/100`.

Comment: It works! Thank you for your fast reply. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

more less coping [nicola's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48078771/how-to-convert-all-values-in-a-column-to-floating-point-values-in-r#comment83131589_48078771) to  provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question and to enable the question to be closed.

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 0:2, A = c('0052', '00558', '0855'), B = c(225L, 
305L, 250L)), .Names = c("ID", "A", "B"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
df
#>   ID     A   B
#> 1  0  0052 225
#> 2  1 00558 305
#> 3  2  0855 250
str(df)
#> 'data.frame':    3 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ ID: int  0 1 2
#>  $ A : chr  "0052" "00558" "0855"
#>  $ B : int  225 305 250
df$A <- as.numeric(df$A)/100
str(df)
#> 'data.frame':    3 obs. of 
#>  $ ID: int  0 1 2
#>  $ A : num  0.52 5.58 8.55
#>  $ B : int  225 305 250
df
#>   ID    A   B
#> 1  0 0.52 225
#> 2  1 5.58 305
#> 3  2 8.55 250
```